# Two classes referencing each other: unknown override specifier error

Tags: c++, header, multiple-inclusions

I'm writing a program to schedule nurses in a hospital. I'm stuck with an inclusion loop between two classes, but I don't know where I made an error. 
There's a nurse class that has an instance of a Preference Profile. This preference profile has a pointer to the Nurse object.

Header of the Nurse class:

```
 //Include guards
#ifndef NURSEDEF
#define NURSEDEF

#pragma once
//Forward declared dependencies
class Department;

//Included dependencies
#include "PrefProfile.h"

//Actual class
class Nurse
{
public:
    Nurse();
    ~Nurse();
    Nurse(string id, Department *dept);
    Nurse(int type, double emplRate, Department *dept);

    Department* getDept();
    string getID();

    bool setType(int type);
    void setEmplRate(double emplRate);
    bool setPrefProfile(int day, int shift, int value);

private:
    string ID;
    double emplRate;
    int type;
    Department *dept;
    PrefProfile pref;
};

#endif
```

Header of the PrefProfile class:

```
//Include guards
#ifndef PREFPROFILEDEF
#define PREFPROFILEDEF

#pragma once
//Forward declared dependencies
class Nurse;

//Included dependencies
#include "Support.h"

//Actual class
class PrefProfile
{

public:
    PrefProfile();
    ~PrefProfile();
    PrefProfile(Nurse *nurse);

    bool addPref(int day, int shift, int pref);
    int readPref(int day, int shift);

private:
    Nurse *nurse;
    int profile[maxDays][maxShifts];
};

#endif
```

As PrefProfile only contains a pointer to a nurse object I forward declared it instead of including the header file. The Nurse class includes the header of PrefProfile. I encounter the following error at the object pref in the Nurse class: C3646 'pref':unknown override specifier.

I'm pretty new to C++ and I read that this approach to reference should be used. Is there an easy way to avoid this kind of inclusion loops? Or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with given code [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0929932b46458c1e). Problem might be in `#include "Support.h"`